# ApolloServer GraphQL Testing

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

Following the documentation here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/testing/  (literally, just copying and pasting and then fixing the typescript errors), I have this code in src/tests/example-test.ts

```
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-express";

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello(name: String): String!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (_: any, { name }: {name: string}) => `Hello ${name}!`,
  },
};

it('returns hello with the provided name', async () => {
  const testServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
  });

  const result = await testServer.executeOperation({
    query: 'query SayHelloWorld($name: String) { hello(name: $name) }',
    variables: { name: 'world' },
  });

  expect(result.errors).toBeUndefined();
  expect(result.data?.hello).toBe('Hello world!')
})
```

gives me this error

```
/src/tests/example-test.ts:15
it('returns hello with the provided name', async () => {
^
ReferenceError: it is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/richard/VSCodeProjects/typescript-graphql-crud-example/src/tests/example-test.ts:15:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/richard/VSCodeProjects/typescript-graphql-crud-example/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:530:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/richard/VSCodeProjects/typescript-graphql-crud-example/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:533:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at main (/Users/richard/VSCodeProjects/typescript-graphql-crud-example/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:212:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/richard/VSCodeProjects/typescript-graphql-crud-example/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:470:3)
```

I would think that I need to import something or say `const it =` something, but the documentation doesn't seem to fill me in on that, or I'm not finding where it does at least.

Comment: "Below is a simplified example of setting up a test using the JavaScript testing library Jest". You need to set up Jest for your test to run. Docs for Jest: https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started

Comment: I would prefer to know how to make "it" defined.

Comment: It will be defined if you set up Jest, since `it` and more are globals: https://jestjs.io/docs/api